# linting in Golang is painfully slow, maybe plugin conflicts?

Tags: filetype-go, plugin-vim-go

I am pretty new to plugin configuration and plugin management when it comes to various languages. My two primary languages that I program in are Go and JavaScript. I use ALE for JavaScript(which works perfectly) however when Programming in Go the linter doesn't really work.
For example. When I open up a new `main.go` file I get the red "X" saying that it is expecting `package` (which is accurate) the problem starts after I enter the `package main` at top. I then leave insert and the error persists. I have to write(`:w`) in order for the error to go away.
When writing in JavaScript the warning/error goes away very shortly after leaving insert mode to normal mode.
my neovim information:

```
NVIM v0.4.4
Build type: Release
```

here is a minimal `.init.vim`:

```
    call plug#begin()

    function! DoRemote(arg)
      UpdateRemotePlugins
    endfunction
    Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': function('DoRemote') }
    Plug 'neomake/neomake', { 'on': 'Neomake' }
    Plug 'ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags'
    Plug 'w0rp/ale'
    Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
    Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
    Plug 'ayu-theme/ayu-vim'
    
    "vim-go
    Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'do': ':GoUpdateBinaries' }


    "Javascript Plugins
    Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
    Plug 'carlitux/deoplete-ternjs'
    Plug 'ternjs/tern_for_vim', { 'do': 'npm install && npm install -g tern' }

    "Typescript Plugins
    Plug 'Shougo/vimproc.vim', { 'do': 'make' }
    Plug 'Quramy/tsuquyomi'
    Plug 'mhartington/deoplete-typescript'

    call plug#end()
        "eslint config
        let g:ale_fixers = {
            \ 'javascript': ['eslint']
            \ }
 
        let g:ale_sign_error = 'X' 
        let g:ale_sign_warning = 'O'
        let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
```

I am not quite sure if there is any additional information that you would like or if this is too much/little information. Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

So my issue was pretty easily fixed. It was my fault. I didn't see the error message when opening up the file that required me to install the binaries with `:GoInstallBinaries` after about 1 minute of binary installation and restarting neovim it was all resolved.